# Where can I find a simple instruction for installing home version of windows office programs in a Ubuntu 12.04 environment

Tags: 12.04

Need help in installing Windows Office in Ubuntu environment

Comment: This is only possible through extra software: you can do it manually with wine or with a kind of installer through Play On Linux. I made an answer with some images using POL. If you got questions please post a comment where my answer is (when your rep allows you ;) ).

Comment: Thank You all. The Office package is legally purchased and hasn't been used before. I'm a very new ubuntu user so I'll check the LibreOffice and test your advice.
Best regards Karl

Answer (score 6):

First off: if possible, I would advise using LibreOffice. If more people use LibreOffice there will be one day a time more people use that than MS Office. Secondly, if you want MS Office use it with a license you bought and did not use on any other machine. Mind the fine print!

1. Install "play on linux" from the repositories. You need to accept the EULA for the Microsoft corefonts.
2. After installing, go through the initial setup.
3. Open Play on Linux if it does not open automatically, and search for Microsoft.

Now for the easy part, since I can finish this with images:

[image: playonlinux install menu]

(note: I have seen office 2010 in the list elsewhere, but it does not show up in my version :( )

[image: playonlinux install wizard]

[image: playonlinux install screen]

[image: playonlinux install screen]

(note: here you need to put the location of your CD/DVD station; before it insert your office CD/DVD into the CD/DVD station). I do not have any MS products at home so the next images are from [tuxtrix.com](http://www.tuxtrix.com/2012/03/install-microsoft-office-2010-in-ubuntu.html).

It should then ask what to install.

[image: playonlinux options]
[image: Word on Ubuntu]

And to top it off, here is a youtube video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XaY1a4hxjpc

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but there is no native Windows Office for ubuntu. You can try to run it with "wine" bit it will probably fail. But there is hope for you. There is "LibreOffice" should be already installed on ubuntu, which is 1:1 to M$Office, maybe even better. Try it

Comment: in fact office7 works fine in wine 1.5 (http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=4992) tested it

Answer (score 0):

Here's a successful guide for Office 2007:

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/easily-install-microsoft-office-2007-linux/

Peter is right though, Office 2010 is a crap shoot though. Unless you need Outlook or Access, I think you will be well served by LibreOffice.

Comment: Please don't just post links. Your answer looses value when that website disappears. If you make some sort of copy from that link and add it in as an answer you are more than likely to get 25+ upvotes ;)

Comment: Fair enough, given the article was over 500 words I was hesitant to do that...

Comment: Posting a short version of the 500 words with a link to the actual document works too if those words cover the basics ;)

Comment: updated 1.5 wine guide here: http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=4992